# Weird noise inside Fresnel glass

Tags: rendering, glass

Have weird effect within the Fresnel material, actually want to produce acrylic. Please help!!
[image]

[image]
After increasing sample and denoising strength 
[image]

Comment: so where is the weird effect? Also maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you have the denoiser on and it created these artifacts because your render contained too much noise or extreme bright highlights. Try to increase the number of samples or increase the feature strength of the denoiser.

Comment: @RUben Clamping should be a last resort, since it literally clamps/clips values limiting the dynamic range and working against effects you'd want to achieve with global illumination. This should only be used in cases like very strong fireflies.

Comment: it does reduce the weird noise, not using clamping though...but they are still there. I increase both denoising and sample

Comment: the result is in the question section

Comment: @yunjun With the current information about the scene it's hard to tell what else you could do.